# Performance testing in a specific browser

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I need to test the performance of a website in a specific browser (IE). Is it possible to do in Jmeter? Or is there any other tool that can do this?

Comment: Please use JMeter Web Driver sampler. It is possible to get end-to-end response time. https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Websites identify client browsers basing on [User-Agent HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) so if you need to mimic IE browser just add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) configured like:

- Name: `User-Agent`
- Value: the relevant User Agent string depending on which IE version you are trying to simulate, like for Internet Explorer 11 it would be

  ```
  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
  ```

  See [Internet Explorer User Agent Strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?name=Internet%20Explorer) for the full list.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't actually "render" the page, it downloads response as plain text so you won't be able to detect any rendering time. It neither executes JavaScript.

links for reference:

- https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser
- https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler